# Migration from OpenLayers 3.4.0 to v3.5.0

Tags: openlayers-3

I followed the migration guidelines specified [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.5.0).
I converted my various ol.source layers as specified from:

```
var source = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
  url: 'features.json',
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

to the new form:

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'features.json',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
```

My feature extents are fine, zoom and position of the map are correct, but I do not see any points/areas on the map (invisible features ?). Could it be related to the vector styles or the render-time loading ?
It worked with 3.4.0 and the old way using `ol.source.GeoJSON`.

Comment: Did you try to remove/comment all `styles` and `setStyle` in your project (default styles are visible)? Your GeoJSON projection is EPSG 4326? Your map projection is EPSG 3857 (default)? This official example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/select-features.html seems to demonstrate there are no issue with your syntax change. Hence, my questions ;)

Comment: You could create a jsfiddle|plunker.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am afraid I will not have time to do a jsfiddle and look at this issue any time soon, but I will come back with more info and look at this example once I get back to it. For the mean while I will stick to 3.4.0

Comment: @ThomasGratier My display projection is EPSG:4326, and my projection is default EPSG:3857, it works well with 3.4.0. I suspect there is an issue with the styles as the map is correctly panning and zooming on the geojson features.